# Why the update command can't be executed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I simplify my problem into a  simple status.

```
mysql> select * from `table`;
+--------+---------+
| f1     | f2      |
+--------+---------+
| hallo  | welcome |
| string | array   |
+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to change the table into the following result.

```
mysql> select * from `table`;
+--------+-------    --+
| f1     | f2          |
+--------+---------+
| hallo  | welcomehaha |
| string | arrayhaha   |
+--------+-------    --+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my code.

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=gbk");
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","root","");

$statement1=$db->prepare("select  f1,f2 from `table`");
$statement1 -> execute();
while($row=$statement1->fetch()){
    $new_content=$row["f1"];
    $new_f2=$row['f2'].'haha';
    echo $new_f2.'</br>';
    $statement2=$db->prepare("update  `table` set f2=$new_f2 where f1={$row['f1']}");
    $statement2 -> execute();
    }    
?>
```

The output is:

```
welcomehaha
arrayhaha
```

The value of `f2` isn't changed, why isn't the `update  'table' set f2=$new_f2 where f1={$row['f1']}`  being executed?

Comment: Because, you haven't quoted your values; they're strings. Plus, you're not checking for errors.

Comment: `...set f2=123haha`... do you have a `123haha` field in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must but your value between single quotation '' because it is text may be it is something like that

```
$statement2=$db->prepare("update  `table` set f2='$new_f2' where f1='{$row['f1']}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement2=$db->prepare("update `table` set `f2`=concat(`f2`,'haha');");
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation to help the op understand instead of just giving him the answer.